# Inverse Laplace transform of $\frac{\sinh(\sqrt z a)}{\sqrt z}$

Tags: complex-analysis, integral-transforms, inverse-laplace

I was trying solve this inverse Laplace transform, given by $\frac{\sinh(\sqrt z a)}{\sqrt z}$, with $a \in \mathbb{R}$. But i dont have any good idea to solve this. Please someone have a idea?

Comment: If you write `\sqrt(z)` MathJax understands that you are writing the square root of `(`  followed by  `z)`. Just write `\sqrt z` . If you need the square root of a bigger expression write `\sqrt{ z+w }`

Comment: Mathematica **13.3.0** gives: `Undefined` .From help pages `Undefined` is a symbol that represents a quantity with no defined value.